# How to combine these two RewriteOptions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm enforcing both https and nonwww in my ASP.Net Core 7 web app, which works great with the following code in Program.cs:

```
var options = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.RewriteOptions()
.AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
.AddRedirectToNonWww(308);
```

The only thing that bugs me is that it uses two consecutive redirects if the source link is both http and www (e.g. http://www.example.com/):

http://www.example.com/
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.example.com/
308 Permanent Redirect
https://example.com/
200 OK

Anyone out there know how to combine this into one redirect? I had it working that way on IIS using rewrite rules in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware) mentioned:

> Use URL Rewriting Middleware when the following approaches aren't
> satisfactory:

> URL Rewrite module with IIS on Windows Server

> Apache mod_rewrite module on Apache Server

> URL rewriting on Nginx

If you insist on trying with middleware I think You could try with [IRule based rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#irule-based-rule)

check the http scheme/host

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Scheme/context.HttpContext.Request.Host
```

set the response statue code/header:

```
 var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
 response.StatusCode = 308;
 response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = newurl
```